# Verify successful post in Facebook .NET sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 RT application. I have installed the facebook and facebook.client sdks for setting up login and sharing purposes. For login purpose I have followed the steps as mentioned [here](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/login/).

My App.xaml.cs OnActivated function looks like this:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnActivated(args);
        var protocolArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        if (protocolArgs != null)
        {
            LifecycleHelper.FacebookAuthenticationReceived(protocolArgs);
        }
        Session.OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished += OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished;

    }
```

and here is OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished method

```
private async void OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished(AccessTokenData session)
    {
        await Session.CheckAndExtendTokenIfNeeded();
        if (Constant.fbSignup)
        {
            User fbUser = new User();
            Account userAccount = new Account();
            try
            {
                FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(session.AccessToken);
                dynamic result = await fbClient.GetTaskAsync("me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,location");
                fbUser.FirstName = result.first_name;
                fbUser.LastName = result.last_name;
                userAccount.UserName = result.email;
                fbUser.UserAccount = userAccount;
                //fbUser.City = result.location.name;
                Constant.User = fbUser;
                RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SignUpPage));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await new MessageDialog(ex.Message).ShowAsync();

            }

        }
```

The login works fine.

Now I want to share some content using the Session.ShowFeedDialog(). I have followed the steps mentioned [here](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/dialog/) for creating AppRequests within the dialog.
I am calling the ShowFeedDialog method this way from a page StoreDetailsPage.xaml.cs
All the following code rests in StorePageDetails.xaml.cs

```
Session.ShowFeedDialog("", link, linkDescription, linkCaption);
```

The posting also works fine. But I need to check whether the post was successful or not. For this purpose I tried the

```
Session.OnFacebookFeedFinished = Success;
```

where success is

```
public delegate void FacebookDelegate(FBResult result);

void Success(FBResult result)
    {
        //Code to check if post was successful
    }
```

So my problem is after ShowFeedDialog is closed the OnActivated event is called and success delegate method is never reached or not called.
I haven't used delegates before so I don't know if there is something wrong there. Also I haven't figured out what the logic for post verification should since I was not able to step into this function. So any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to check if the post was successful?

Comment: I have something of a point system for post sharing.

Comment: Facebook platform policy doesn't allow that and if you do it anyway your app will be banned

Comment: The content to share is solely with consent of user and the user will have an option if he wants to share something or not.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The policy say you are not allowed to incentives anyone

Comment: So you are saying if I remove the point system then it is okay if the user shares content from the app? Like right now I am offering him five points for sharing content on facebook which is a kind of incentive right?

Comment: @WizKid [Here](http://i.imgur.com/csO9O69.png) is the screenshot of a sample post. The content is okay I suppose.

Comment: It is not about the content – you are not allowed to reward users for sharing. https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse, 4.5 – the image behind the question mark should make it even more clear.

Comment: @CBroe Ok I get it now. Thanks for the help.